# Cannot Populate Mongodb with new req.body.xxxx data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am stuck trying to update MongoDB with added req.body.whatever data.

When I get the req.body data to my route, I can see it, change it and update to the database just fine, but when I add say, a new element into the req.body like so:

```
req.body.newData = "this is new";
```

In the route, it will not populate into MongoDB with the rest of the existing (changeable) req.body data that already exists in the DB document. 
I can in code change an existing req.body.(KeyElement), and updates fine to the DB. Once I try to add an element to req.body, the new one just doesn't get updated. Tried all different update, modify, replaceOne etc and can get an editable result, but still no new elements being added to the database. I even tried the

```
Model.update(query, {$set: req.body});   etc
```

and this seems to update as well but nothing new gets added.

Here is the route I'm working with...

```
router.post('/set-repair-info', ensureAuthenticatedAdmin, function(req, res) {
  console.log('set-repair-info : ');
  var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
  var b = req.body;
  console.log('body: ');
  console.log(req.body);
  var repairToUpdate = req.body.jid;
  // console.log(repairToUpdate);
  // console.log('req.body[uid]');
  // console.log(req.body.jid);
  // console.log('userid::: ' + req.body.userid);
  // console.log('backuped :   ' + req.body.backedup);
  // console.log(req.body.username);

  //buggy without this;
  if (req.body.backedup=='false'){
    req.body.backedup == '';
  }

  //CHECKS AND RESPONSES:
  //by Edit
  //PARTS ORDERED
  if(req.body.repairstatus == 'Parts Ordered'){
    req.body.partsordered = 'true';    //THIS WILL NOT GO INTO DB!
  } else{
    req.body.partsordered = null;
  }

  req.body.testthisout = "THIS IS A TEST";  //THIS WILL NOT GO INTO DB!
  console.log("parts: " + req.body.partsordered);

  // Job.replaceOne({ _id: ObjectId(req.body.jid)}, req.body , {upsert: true}, function (err, result) {
  //     (err === null) ? {msg: 'something happened... err edit user'} : {msg: err}
  // });
  console.log('body updated: ');
  console.log(req.body);
  req.body.repairstatus = "Waiting For Something Else";  // UPDATES FINE

  Job.update({ _id: ObjectId(req.body.jid)}, { $set: req.body },  function (err, result) {
      (err === null) ? {msg: 'something happened... err edit user'} : {msg: err}
  });

  req.flash('success_msg','Repair has successfully been edited and saved to the database.');
  res.render('edit-repair', { job: {'data': req.body} });

});
```

Comment: I have to make note that the "THIS DOE NOT UPDATE" comment lines are the created elements in the route, and are not passed when the route gets called. They are updated in the route, and can be seen in console.log of req.body. I also checked the Model.js Schema holding this and made sure the element is in there. I MAY NEED TO RECREATE! Will test that now and report back.

Comment: still same results.

Comment: You could try turning off [strict](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) mode for a while to check if the problem lies with the model.

Comment: Do the new fields exist in your Mongoose Schema?

Comment: Working now. 
Wasn't in Schema and last attempt to add and check supposedly didn't make it to the saved file. Saved and now working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check your Models Schema and make sure variable is setup there.
Check your routes that create an instance of the Schema, make sure value is in there. And .save() or update through mongoose method.
SAVE the file.